# How can I show multiple variables for an increasing number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was planning to use an increasing variable to increase a variable, yet I don't know how.

I Tried using this code:

```
C = 1
while True:
 C = C+1 
 print (f'{C}')
M = C*0.1
if M == 1:
 C = 1*3
print (f'{C}')
print (f'{M}')`
```

Comment: dont use single space for indent. use four space as is standard.

Comment: that first while loop is supposed to do that. I'm wondering how/if you you can show multiple increasing variables at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

dont use single space for indent. use four space as is standard.

otherwise you wouldve caught the issue: the first `while` loop is seemingly eternal. it halt exec of the code and never it reach `L5`.

```py
C = 1
while True:
 C = C+1 
 print (f'{C}')
# never it reach to here
> M = C*0.1   # <-- nope!!
if M == 1:
 C = 1*3
```

The sol'n is to fix all of the indent, and then nest it within a loop such as `while`, and then use a statement to exit out of the infinite loop, with a statement such as `break` for ex. as below

```py
C = 1
while True:
        C = C + 1
        print(f'{C}')
        M = C * 0.1  # <-- nope!! previously, but is all good now.
        if M == 1: 
                    # not really, I think, since we're exiting the loop, we don't need
                    # here to set C as again, since it won't be evaluate ever again.
                    # C = 1 * 3
                    break  # <-- need!! to exit out of infinite program-killer code
```

This is the results I am get:

```py
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: it can be useful. I just showed above how can be the utility of it. the important thing is, if the condition `M == 1` is true (in this case), then we need a stmnt to break out of the infinite loop when a condition is met.